# calling the same ADO.NET Command several times within the scope of a single transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ado.net

My question concerns how to insert multiple line items on an Order, for example, within the scope of a single transaction.

All of the line items must be inserted or the transaction must be rolled back.

Can multiple inserts to the same table be done without sending a custom CLR object as a parameter, equivalent to a table-valued parameter? Can MyInsertSingleLineItemCommand be called inside a loop, inserting one line item with each invocation? Do we need an intermediary temporary table?

Comment: Sure. There is a SqlTransaction class in dotnet that you can use to begin/commit/rollback. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but a table valued parameter would be more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can multiple inserts to the same table be done without sending a
>   custom CLR object as a parameter, equivalent to a table-valued
>   parameter?

Yes you can do row by row in a single transaction using SqlTransaction.

> Can MyInsertSingleLineItemCommand be called inside a loop, inserting
>   one line item with each invocation?

Yes example code below.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING")
{
     cn.Open();
     using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction()) 
     {
          // your looping code here persisting to sql server db
          tr.Commit();
     }
}
```

You can also accomplish this using [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
   {
      connection.Open();
      // your looping code here persisting to sql server db
   }

   ts.Complete();
}
```

> Do we need an intermediary temporary table?

No you do not require a temporary table.

That being said you may want to consider using [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Table Value Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to pass your data to Sql Server. Though it depends on your requirements.

[More info here on TVPs](http://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/).